# AWS JAVA ElasticsearchClient cluster and index lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

What AWS Elasticsearch Java API do I use to point to AWS ElasticsearchClient cluster and determine if an index exists in the cluster?

## 1 Edit:

Here is how to point to the cluster:

```
String endpoint = "search-name-ppb6tuag3s4srci5qwou6eumru.us-region-x.es.amazonaws.com";
es_client = new AWSElasticsearchClient( new BasicAWSCredentials(key,secret), clientConfig);    
es_client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
```

## 2 Edit:

AWS Elastic documentation points to Elastic elastic.co API. And elastic.co API is referencing their transport API:

```
client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(endpoint,9300)));
```

BUT!!! AWS ES engine doesn't support transport 9300 endpoint, so the decision is made to use Java HTTP Resp API instead. I sure wish AWS documentation was a lot more explicit about it, I've killed a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: That library can only be used to configure Amazon Elasticsearch, i.e. it's a configuration API to create, configure, and manage Elasticsearch domains, but not for interacting with Elasticsearch. For that the existing answer provides a solution.

Comment: @val: I thought I'd have to use AWSElasticsearchClient because of AWS authentication. Do you know by any chance how I would authenticate with AWS if using org.elasticsearch.client.Client library?

Answer (score -1):

You can use client admin interface to check whether the index with name *INDEX_NAME* exists or not synchronously

```
boolean exists = client.admin().indices()
    .prepareExists(INDEX_NAME)
    .execute().actionGet().isExists();
```

Comment: I've tried creating client you're referring to with 2.3 elasticsearch library, but had no luck, was only getting errors "None of the configured nodes are available", I thought it must be authentication issue, so I started looking at AWS lib instead.

Comment: Can you access your elasticsearch cluster from your local box using a basic curl ? Also check if you could telnet on AWS box through port 9300

Comment: I can do curl locally to get a health check info for the AWS elastic. I have been trying 9300 and 80. To run curl I have to do it without the port reference.

Comment: I wont be able to use org.elasticsearch.client all together, please see my edit #2.